# QR factorization of two vertically stacked upper triangular matrix using Givens Rotation

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

In this problem, I am trying to compute the QR factorization of two vertically stacked upper triangular matrix using Givens Rotation. So, I'm trying to zero out all the non zero entries in the `r_2` matrix column by column. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la

np.random.seed(10)
B = np.random.rand(4,2)

q_1 , r_1 = la.qr(B[:2, :2])
q_2 , r_2 = la.qr(B[2:4, :2])

R_12 = np.vstack((r_1, r_2))

def givens(a, b):
    c = a / np.sqrt(a **2+ b**2)
    s = b / np.sqrt(a **2+ b**2)
    return c, s

m, n = R_12.shape
Q5 = np.eye(m)
R_tmp = R_12.copy()

for j in range(n): # columns
    for i in range(j+1): # row
        c , s = givens(R_tmp[j,j], R_tmp[n+i,j])
        Q = np.eye(m)
        Q[j,j] = c
        Q[j, n+i] = s
        Q[n+i, j] = -s
        Q[n+i, n+i] = c
 
        Q5 = Q5 @ Q
        R_tmp = Q @ R_tmp
print(R_tmp)
```

The final upper triangular output `R_tmp` looks like this

```
[[ 1.13321832e+00  6.64638268e-01]
 [-9.01587953e-19  8.65063215e-01]
 [-3.70107044e-18  6.42047272e-19]
 [ 9.38337336e-19  8.16113029e-17]]
```

But checking with the correct answer from the qr function in scipy

```
q5, r5 =la.qr(R_12)

print(r5, "\n")
```

it gives

```
[[ 1.13321832  0.66463827]
 [ 0.         -0.86506322]
 [ 0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.        ]]
```

So, the first row of my `R_tmp` matrix looks fine, but there is an extra negative sign in the second row of my `R_tmp` matrix compared to the correct answer given by scipy. And I'm stuck to figure out where exactly is the problem that causes the extra negative sign in the second row. Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can flip the sign of any rows of R as long as you flip the sign of the corresponding column of Q. The new factorisation is still a valid QR factorisation of your original matrix. This can be seen by taking a diagonal matrix S with diagonal elements in {-1,+1}. Premultiplying a matrix by S changes the signs of the rows corresponding to -1 elements of S, while postmultiplying changes the sign of the corresponding columns. Then:

A = QR = Q I R = Q S S R = (Q S) (S R) = Q2 R2.

The QR factorisation of a full-rank square matrix (as well as the thin QR factorisation of a full-rank rectangular matrix) is unique only if we follow the convention of flipping the signs to make the diagonal entries of R positive.

Answer (score 0):

Your updating of the factorization is wrong in one point. If Q,R are the intermediate factors, R not fully triangular, and $G$ is the givens rotation for the current step, then you want

```
A = Q @ R = (Q @ G.T) @ (G @ R)
```

the factors that you add inside the product have to cancel to the unity matrix, using that the inverse of any orthogonal matrix is also its transpose.

---

The standard for QR decompositions is the use of Householder reflectors. This variant does not guarantee the signs on the R diagonal. In the extreme case the QR decomposition of the identity can result in `Q = R = -I`